# Power set of a set containing sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i was trying to figure out what is the power set of:

$$\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$$

my solution is that the only element of the set is $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$
than the power set is $\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$.
i got to my solution by substituting the empty set with the variable a and the set containing the a with b and so on, is this an mathematically correct thing to do?

Comment: *Hint*: your candidate cannot be the power set of any set, since for all $A$ set, $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Remember that the empty set an the set itself are always subset.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal P(\{x\})=\{\varnothing,\{x\}\}$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path with regards to changing the variable.

If you can tell what is $\mathcal P(\{x\})$, and you understand that the exact content of $x$ does not matter much to the outcome of the power set, then taking $x=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ will give you the answer.

The most important thing to remember here is that membership and subset are two different and often unrelated relations. If $x\in y$ it need not be that $x\subseteq y$, and if $x\in y$ and $y\in z$, it need not be the case that $x\in z$.

Comment: I should have emphasized that last point in class last week. I will go over it again on Tuesday.

Comment: so if I am  following you correctly : {empty set , {{empty set}}}

Comment: Not quite. $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ is an *element* of $\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$, but it is not a subset.

Comment: thanks a lot i think i got it now :-) see you Tuesday